# Code hangs when trying to run code, telegram bot deployment

Tags: python, bots, telegram

I am trying to compile some python code and run it as a telegram bot.
When I run it on VS Code or in the CMD console (python main.py) it freezes.

However, when I broke up the code individually and run, it works well.

1) Can any PyGod point out where im doing wrong?
2) I realised this happens when I try to redeploy a telegram bot too. Anyone have ideas on this?

```
from telegram.ext import Updater, InlineQueryHandler, CommandHandler
from telegram.ext.dispatcher import run_async
import requests
import re

def get_url():

    contents = requests.get('https://dog.ceo/api/breed/retriever/golden/images/random').json()
    url = contents['message']   
    return url

def get_image_url():

    allowed_extension = ['jpg','jpeg','png']
    file_extension = ''
    while file_extension not in allowed_extension:
        url = get_url()
        file_extension = re.search("([^.]*)$",url).group(1).lower()
    return url

@run_async
def goodboy(update, context):
  url = get_image_url()
  chat_id = update.message.chat_id
  context.bot.send_photo(chat_id=chat_id, photo=url)

def main():

    updater = Updater('YOUR_TOKEN', use_context=True)
    dp = updater.dispatcher
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler('goodboy',goodboy))
    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: The indentation of the `def goodboy()` seems wrong, typo?